# Splice and insert an array to another

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, slice, splice

The definition of the algorithm problem is:

***You are given two arrays and an index. Use the array methods slice and splice to copy each element of the first array into the second array, in order. Begin inserting elements at index n of the second array. Return the resulting array. The input arrays should remain the same after the function runs.***

*Example: frankenSplice([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], 1) should return [4, 1, 2, 3, 5].*

My question is that why cannot I simply splice arr2 and put arr1 into it as explained in the code. Why do I have to slice arr2 into another variable and do the splicing?

```
function frankenSplice(arr1, arr2, n) {



 //Why do I have to slice this? 
  let localArr = arr2.slice();  
  localArr.splice(n, 0, ...arr1);  
  return localArr; 
}
```

Why doesn't the code below work? What is the matter with that?

```
//My solution: 

function frankentSplice(arr1, arr2, n) {

  arr2.splice(n, 0, ...arr1); 
  return arr2; 
}
```

Comment: The quesion requires **The input arrays should remain the same after the function runs**.  `arr2.splice` may change the arr2 and the localArr make the copy of arr2.

Comment: I understand now why it does not work.